# Layout features in angular material

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

Could anyone help with below issue, it's eating my head.

I was trying to build similar website like gitlab, any idea how to build feature like container fuild limited( I inspected the div from browser) in angular material. Generally fixing a div in the middle and become responsive when it overflow the particular div

Comment: Please, can you better describe what you're trying to achieve? Can you show us your current implementation and tell us what is not working in it?

Comment: I am working for a organisation, we are not allowed to publish the code, I was trying to create a website which is responsive like gitlab website in angular materia(div in the middle of page has to be of some specific height and width, when I resize the screen the div should not be responsive, it should just adjust the screen, if the screen becomes smaller than div height and width then the div has to become responsive) any idea how to achive, I tried mat-grid but didn't work